# How can insert a jlabel inside a jdesktop pane in netbeans. When i tried to drag and drop it didn't work? The desktop pane got displaced

Tags: netbeans

I also tried to enclose the label inside a dekstop pane. But a message flashed that cannot enclose components in a non-empty container. Any help shall be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Using Netbeans 11.0 I was able to drag a `JLabel` into a `JDesktopPane` and I did not see the error you reported. However I believe that `JDesktopPane` was designed just to be a container for `JInternalFrame`s rather than having other components embedded directly. This was for MDI applications that aren't seen so much these days.
Have a look at the relevant [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for background info.
I have also put a minimal example here which you can paste into an empty class in Netbeans

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JDesktopPane desktop_pane = new JDesktopPane();
    frame.getContentPane().add(desktop_pane);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
        JInternalFrame internal = new JInternalFrame(String.format("Window %d", i), true, true, true, true);
        internal.setSize(150, 80);
        internal.setLocation(i * 50, i * 50);
        internal.setVisible(true);
        desktop_pane.add(internal);
    }
    desktop_pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.pack();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

It will create a desktop with five resizeable windows in it.